# Is there a hotkey (or a way to hotkey) to cycle grease pencil brushes?

Tags: shortcut, grease-pencil

I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to the draw mode. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to select the draw tool. Is there a hotkey to select the brush I want or cycle through them?